# invoke C api with tidesdk

Tags: tidesdk

Could you please help me how to call/invoke plain C API from DLL file with JavaScript or Python or PHP language with TideSDK?

Thanks and best regards,
Phuong Tang Khai,

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate how exactly that you wanna call the APIs. and what kind of APIs you are talking about. There are already various modules available which provides decent functionality available already.

However if you don't find required functionality, you can create your own custom module and plug it in with TideSDK.

The call to APIs needs to be wrapped up as custom modules of Tide and has to be built along with TideSDK.